Many to Many mapping using Micronaut Data does not persist data
I have 2 entities - a Question and a TestPaper. The mapping between both should be many to many given that a test paper can have many questions and a question can belong in many test papers.
@Serdeable
@MappedEntity
data class Question(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(Type.AUTO) val id: Long? = null,
    var department: String,
    var courseId: Long,
    var questionText: String,
    var questionType: String,
    var mediaUri: String?,

    @Relation(value = MANY_TO_MANY, cascade = [ALL])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "test_paper_question",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "question_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "test_paper_id")]
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    var testPapers: MutableList<TestPaper> = mutableListOf()
)

@Serdeable
@MappedEntity
data class TestPaper(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(GeneratedValue.Type.AUTO) val id: Long? = null,
    var department: String,
    var courseId: Long,
    @Relation(value = MANY_TO_MANY, mappedBy = "testPapers")
    var questions: MutableList<Question> = mutableListOf()
)

This how I add a question to a test paper and also retrieve it
@Singleton
open class TestPaperService(
    private val testPaperRepository: TestPaperRepository,
    private val questionRepository: QuestionRepository
) {
    @Transactional
    open fun addQuestionToTestPaper(testPaperId: Long, questionId: Long): TestPaper {
        val testPaper = testPaperRepository.findById(testPaperId).orElseThrow {
            RuntimeException("TestPaper not found with id: $testPaperId")
        }
        val question = questionRepository.findById(questionId).orElseThrow {
            RuntimeException("Question not found with id: $questionId")
        }

        testPaper.questions.add(question)
        question.testPapers.add(testPaper)

        testPaperRepository.update(testPaper)
        questionRepository.update(question)

        return testPaper
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    open fun getQuestionsForTestPaper(testPaperId: Long): List<Question> {
        val testPaper = testPaperRepository.findById(testPaperId).orElseThrow {
            RuntimeException("TestPaper not found with id: $testPaperId")
        }
        return testPaper.questions
    }
}

I have written this test including print statements to see what the operations are doing -
@Test
    fun `test addQuestionToTestPaper adds a question successfully`() {

        val question = Question(department = "Computer Science", courseId = 1, questionText = "What is calculus?", questionType = "Multiple Choice", mediaUri = null, testPapers = mutableListOf())
        val savedQuestion = questionRepository.save(question)

        val testPaper = TestPaper(department = "Computer Science", courseId = 1, questions = mutableListOf())
        val savedTestPaper = testPaperRepository.save(testPaper)

        val updatedTestPaper = testPaperService.addQuestionToTestPaper(savedTestPaper.id!!, savedQuestion.id!!)
        val retrieved = testPaperService.getQuestionsForTestPaper(savedTestPaper.id!!)
        val retrievedAfterUpdate = testPaperRepository.findById(3L)

        println("saved: $savedTestPaper")
        println("updated: $updatedTestPaper")
        println("retrieved: $retrievedAfterUpdate")

        assertTrue(retrieved.any { it.id == savedQuestion.id })
        assertTrue(savedQuestion.testPapers.any { it.id == savedTestPaper.id })
    }

The results of the print statements were:
saved: TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=0)
updated: TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=1)
retrieved: Optional[TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=0)]

As you can see the return from the update operation has the question but the retrieval from the database does not have any reference.
Here are the logs of the operations
01:04:24.147 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing Query: SELECT question_."id",question_."department",question_."course_id",question_."question_text",question_."question_type",question_."media_uri" FROM "question" question_ WHERE (question_."id" = ?)
01:04:24.150 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing SQL query: UPDATE "test_paper" SET "department"=?,"course_id"=? WHERE ("id" = ?)
01:04:24.152 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing SQL query: UPDATE "question" SET "department"=?,"course_id"=?,"question_text"=?,"question_type"=?,"media_uri"=? WHERE ("id" = ?)
01:04:24.158 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing SQL query: UPDATE "test_paper" SET "department"=?,"course_id"=? WHERE ("id" = ?)
01:04:24.162 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing SQL query: INSERT INTO "test_paper_question" ("question_id","test_paper_id") VALUES (?,?)
01:04:24.167 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing Query: SELECT test_paper_."id",test_paper_."department",test_paper_."course_id" FROM "test_paper" test_paper_ WHERE (test_paper_."id" = ?)
01:04:24.168 [Test worker] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing Query: SELECT test_paper_."id",test_paper_."department",test_paper_."course_id" FROM "test_paper" test_paper_ WHERE (test_paper_."id" = ?)
saved: TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=0)
updated: TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=1)
retrieved: Optional[TestPaper(id=3, department='Computer Science', courseId=1, questions=0)]
01:04:24.175 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.t.j.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@193383192 wrapping org.testcontainers.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper@3bb9ca38]
01:04:24.176 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.t.j.DataSourceTransactionManager - Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@193383192 wrapping org.testcontainers.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper@3bb9ca38] auto-commit [true]

I tried using JPA and now Micronaut's own Data and JDBC (I know it is not an ORM and more of a data mapper) but I get the same results using both. I even tried to switch to a One to Many where a test paper can have many questions but I simply am not able to get questions to map to test papers.
